# Creating Tview with navigation

Tags: go, user-interface, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to build a simple todo list with [Tview](https://github.com/rivo/tview) having taken a look of the documentation and ran the presentation demo. I'd like to create todo list with a that includes a navigation pane that'll have some buttons such that you can create todos:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/rivo/tview"
)

func main() {
    app := tview.NewApplication()

    flex := tview.NewFlex().
        AddItem(tview.NewBox().SetBorder(true).SetTitle("List notes"), 0, 1, false).
        AddItem(tview.NewFlex().SetDirection(tview.FlexRow).
            AddItem(tview.NewBox().SetBorder(true).SetTitle("Navigation"), 5, 2, false).
            AddItem(tview.NewBox().SetBorder(true).SetTitle("Pane for creating note"), 0, 1, false), 0, 3, false)
    if err := app.SetRoot(flex, true).Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Which outputs: [image: screenshot]

Is it possible to nest `tview.NewButton()` inside a `tview.NewBox()`. Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

Just reading [the doc](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rivo/tview#pkg-index) (and more specifically the types' description) :

- it looks like this library uses methods named `Add<Something>` to nest an object within another,
- taking `Flex.AddItem(item Primitive, ...)` as an example : a general "Add anything" method will probably take a variable of type `Primitive` as an argument (you will note that [`Primitive` is an interface](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rivo/tview#Primitive), which matches the idea "it can be any concrete type", such as a Label or a Button or ...),
- there may be specialized versions, e.g. : type `Form` has an [`AddButton(label string, selected func())`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/rivo/tview#Form.AddButton) method.

---

With that in mind, I'd say that to add a button somewhere :

- you can use `AddItem(tview.NewButton(label).SetSelectedFunc(onSelected), ...)` on a `Flex` or a `Grid`
- you can use `Form.AddButton(label, onSelected)` with a `Form`

You can also add buttons to a `Modal`.

The other `Add...` methods I see do not seem to fit the bill.